# python 3, can't understand import system

Tags: python-3.x

this is such a simple problem but I cant seem to find any direct explanation to this.

in module.py

```
def foo():
 print("foo")
```

in main.py

```
import module
foo()
```

it will result in an error saying that foo is not defined? when i look for the answer online, I can't find anything surprisingly

I'm not planning to use things like

```
from x import y
```

just straight up the import system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import an external module, it generates a variable named module that contains all classes, functions and variables from the module. To acess 'foo' function you need to first acess the module:

```
module.foo()
```

To import 'foo' function you can import everything from the module, like this:

```
from module import *
```

Now you can simply do: foo()

You can also set a custom name to the module, like:

```
import module as M
```

And now you can run 'foo' like this:

```
M.foo()
```

PS: I'm not english native

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
import module
```

makes the name of module `module` available.  So you can use `module.foo()`.

If you want to call `foo()` without "qualifying" it:

```
from module import foo
```

or

```
from module import *
```

but that latter is bad idea because you are liable to import unexpected names, which may collide with other names you imported from other modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
from model import foo
```

is the preferred way as in any kinds of

`from model import *`

you (and anyone ever working on that code) has no idea what has been imported. Could even lead to name conflicts.